# Copying the files and SUBDIRECTORIES based on modification date?

Tags: date, terminal, find, copy

It may be a duplicate question but i could not find the solution for this i want to copy a last 3 months files AND subdirectories from one disk to andother but i could find only to listing the files by using the following command. I really don't know how to copy the files by using -mtime. I'm new to linux please help me.

```
 find . -mtime -90 -exec cp {} targetdir \;
```

but how to copy directories with subdirectories and files too? (but do not use command rsync, i don;t have it with this instance) Regards S.

Comment: Try specify recursive option in copy i.e. find . -mtime -90 -exec cp -R {} targetdir \;

Answer (score 0):

Copy needs a recursive option specified to handle the subdirectories

```
$ find testroot  # shows some dirs and files
testroot
testroot/sub1
testroot/sub1/subtestfile
testroot/sub2
testroot/testf

$ find target  # empty at this stage
target

$ find ./testroot/ -exec cp -R {} target/ \;

$ find target
target
target/sub1
target/sub1/subtestfile
target/sub2
target/subtestfile
target/testf
```

Comment: But i don't know name of subdir! I just want to automatic select and copy folders no older then 90 days!